# Is putting c# code in a code-behind and compiling it to a DLL any more secure than an inline <script> block?

Tags: c#, security

I constantly have to do little 10-line code snippets for customer websites.  Other people in my office are now asking me to put the code in DLLs, as the code sometimes contains a password for a 3rd party webservice, or something else of similar security.  Is it actually any more secure if compiled to a DLL?

Comment: Someone might be less likely to *stumble across* a password compiled into a DLL, but no it's not actually any more secure.

Comment: You're talking about inline C# script blocks or inline JavaScript blocks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. It's classic security by obscurity and can be easily revealed in a decompiler.

Comment: You don't even need a decompiler.  Just a hex editor and a little curiousity :-)

Comment: This may warrant a question of its own, but here goes:  Where should I put a username and password to a 3rd party webservice?

Comment: @JordanHudson: in a `web.config` file protected with Regiis.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably slightly more secure, but not by very much.  If you are not taking steps to encrypt the passwords, it is only slightly harder to open a DLL in a binary editor and hunt for passwords if you suspect there's something interesting in the DLL.

Either approach is not very secure.

Answer (score 1):

The C# code in the script block is still compiled into a script block. The difference is that the aspx (presumed) that it lives in is published to the server. If the client can access this then code security is the last thing to be concerned about.

Same thing goes for the dll. Presumable this is a web application. The client should never have your DLLs (which can be decompiled anyway!).

Answer (score 0):

If its things like db connection strings with password information inside of it, you can put that into the connectionStrings section of the web.config.  And then you can encrypt that section of the web.config file.  And you should still be able to access those connection strings from C# script blocks in the aspx pages.